Какие гарантии есть для пути в макросе "__FILE__"?
Я хочу проверить, что определённый подпуть есть в __FILE__. Судя по тестам он всегда даёт путь начиная с корня проекта. Могу ли я на это полагаться или он может дать и абсолютный путь? Если не могу, то есть ли альтернативы __FILE__ с тем же поведением, но с большими гарантиями?

В стандарте только "__FILE__ The presumed name of the current source file (a character string literal)." Так что гарантии нет. Можно еще посмотреть, где реализовано static consteval source_location current() noexcept;, но там тоже о полном пути не сказано...

Нет даже никаких гарантий, что там вообще будет путь к файлу. Напрер gcc может компилировать из stdin и __FILE__ заменяется на что-то вроде "(source)".

@user7860670 мне надо макрос в хедере, поведение которого зависит от того, кто его включает; для этого ставлю в нём #define macro { if (__FILE__.contains("/some/path") do_smth(); else { do_smth_else(); }; норм ли так делать учитывая что гарантий нет или для этой проблемы есть лучше решения? Делать разные хедеры нежелательно (чтобы юзер всегда 1 включал и не думал), не макрос использовать не могу (т.к. надо подстановка именно на месте вызова), варианта как прокинуть дефайны через билд систему тоже не вижу

@Harry я бы попробовал какое-то библиотечное решение типа source_location, но у меня специфичное требование в том, что это должен быть макрос, чтобы он раскрывался в разный путь в зависимости от того какой .cpp его инклюдит, см. коммент выше

Это похоже на проблему XY. Стоило бы задавать вопрос именно про это и привести там пример заголовочного файла и его использования. А то непонятно, что там вы мутите.

XY - это точно... "Чтоб пользователь не задумывался". Он, не задумываясь, переименует исходник или перенесет с места на место, и все :(

@user7860670 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1575511/564190

@Harry https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1575511/564190
