Как сделать макрос в хедере с разным поведением в сорсах?
Хочу сделать макрос для логирования такой, чтобы в одних файлах он автоматически писал одно имя бинаря, в других - другое. То есть у меня есть проект
utils
- logger
  - logger.h
app_1
- ...
- main.cpp
- app_1_file.cpp
app_2
- ...
- main.cpp
- app_2_file.cpp

Я хочу чтобы в файлах app_1 мой вызов макроса LOG("hello") выдавал надпись from app_1: hello, а в файлах app_2 - from app_2: hello. Для этого в макросе делаю что-то вроде (псевдокод):
#define LOG(text) if (__FILE__.contains("app_1")) std::print("from app_1: {}", text); else std::print("from app_2: {}", text)

Но в соседнем вопросе говорят, что вывод __FILE__ не гарантирован. Норм ли такое решение или можно лучше сделать?
Проблема в том, что использовать не макрос я не могу, т.к. на самом деле у меня не std::print, а другой макрос из сторонней библиотеки для логирования, который требует раскрытия на месте вызова (чтобы правильно подхватить строчки и т.п.)

Нормальный вариант, именно для этого __FILE__ и предназначен. Это путь, по которому препроцессор открыл файл. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html

Так и напишите функцию, которая возвращает имя текущего бинарного файла.  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1045770/%d0%a1-%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%83-%d1%81-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bc

@Chorkov хм, звучит как решение, но не уверен, что оно лучше - всё таки системный вызов делать в каждой попытке логирования?

@Никита Если хотите оптимизации - сделайте глобальную (или статическую - внутри функции)  переменную, которая будет инициализироваться один раз.
